# Rigid body: how to display collision margin in Blender 3D?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

Hello I'd like to display the collision margins in rigid body simulation how could I do with objects and particles ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to see the hitboxes of the objects with rigid bodies (the collision shape), you have to do nothing. Usually they are shown on top of the object. If you cannot see them, try to set the Viewport shader to in **WireFrame**. If you still cannot see the hitbox its because the shape box is set to **Mesh**, so it overlaps with the current mesh. If your intent was to see a bigger hitbox for objects with an higher collision margin. I don't know if that's possible.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

First change the *Collision Shape* to *Mesh*. Then set the *Sensitivity Margin* to `0.00`. Play the animation.